# How do I talk to Spanish 112 in English?

Tags: spain, emergencies

I called 112 yesterday intending to report a fire along the highway and heard some sort of recorded message. Unfortunately, I don’t speak Spanish well enough to understand the message, leaving me to wonder how to proceed. Ultimately, I decided to hang up the phone.

How do I reach the right person for the language and emergency?

Answer (score 4):

Based on Internet research, the answer is simple:

After calling 112, just wait for an operator to answer. The operator will most likely understand English enough to get the details of the emergency.

The recorded message was probably to inform me that my call was placed in a queue and would be answered as soon as possible. I should have waited longer.

Comment: "Based on a conversation with ChatGPT and other Internet research": it would be better not to rely on a toy to develop your strategy for addressing life-threatening situations.

Comment: @phoog I agree, and hope someone kmowledgeable about the process can come along and verify or make corrections.

Comment: Based on the European Emergency Number Assiciation website https://eena.org/about-112/whats-112-all-about/ this answer is correct - the website states that callers should wait until an operator answers their call

Comment: @Traveller your comment looks like the correct answer. Do you want to post that as an answer, or add those details in the OP's answer?

Comment: That's the same as when I had to call an ambulance in Switzerland 25 years ago - the operator's English and my German got over the basics. For a common language like English, there's a good chance you'll be transferred to someone nearly fluent to give more details if necessary.